# Alternative to Firebug for Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firebug

The latest versions of Firebug in Firefox feel like they've been regressing. Performance is abysmal. This is a common complaint amongs everyone on my team, and increasingly among many other web developers online.

Are there any alternative extensions for Firefox that gives similar functionality(DOM inspector, Net tab, console)?

Comment: I agree.  The last few versions do appear to have regressed.  The performance is poor compared to versions from a year ago.  I am here as a result of my frustration with the performance.  @johnjbarton how do we post problems debugging internal projects that we cannot release to the general public?

Comment: Chromium/Chrome has a great debugger. Firefox is better, but Chromium/Chrome's debugger can handle some situations where Firebug crashes or messes up the page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firefox now has built in developer tools similar to Firebug, but not so full-featured:

https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/technology/

http://www.webmonkey.com/2011/12/an-overview-of-firefoxs-coming-developer-tools/

Comment: Hope we can also use the firefox's [Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/)

Answer (score 6):

[Fidler Web Debugger](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is an option, although it's not as integrated.

Other alternatives include:

- [Jash: Javascript Shell](http://www.billyreisinger.com/jash/)
- [Internet Explorer Developer Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18359)
- [FireAtlas](http://fireatlas.chesnaistechnologies.com/) (extension to FireBug, but helps debug ASP.NET)

Answer (score 2):

The IE8 Debugger is pretty good, for IE. They seemingly took several cues from Firebug.

Comment: @The Matt: The Developer Toolbar is not compatible with Internet Explorer 8. Please use the developer tools included with Internet Explorer 8.  Press F12 or click the 'Developer Tools' entry in the Tools menu to begin using the tool.

Comment: I was asking about Firefox though, not IEx. I do use the developer tools in IE8 when necessary, but not that often.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you as far as Firebug's performance goes in recent releases, therefore I have found myself using the excellent [WebKit Inspector](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/UsingtheWebInspector/UsingtheWebInspector.html) - in both Chrome and Safari - and [Opera Dragonfly](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/) a lot more recently.

Comment: Those are both great, but the OP was asking specifically about a Firefox extension.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to post your specific problems about Firebug performance to the Firebug newsgroup or bug list, then we'd just fix them. No one has ever complained about performance. We had some problems with memory but these were fixed.
jjb

Comment: More suitable as a comment than an answer

Comment: "No one has ever complained about performance" Are you kidding me? It slows the browser a lot

Comment: Startup time *sucks*. I cannot put it less bluntly, and it's as evident as a gorilla in a small room. Firefox 4 is the fastest starting browser, unless you install firebug. I use a second profile for those times I **must** run firebug. `firefox.exe -P` to configure it, for those interested, and `firefox.exe -P profilename` to run it in a given profile.

Comment: No one has complained about performance? Do you think we're stupid?

Comment: I was going to flag this as "not an answer" but I'd rather have it left here for the other comments. Firebug is a memory black hole

Answer (score 0):

Check out 
[Dung Beetle](http://andrewray.me/dung-beetle/index.html)

Also, exclusively for XPath expressions, but pretty fast,
[XPath Checker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/xpath-checker/)

Answer (score 0):

For Http/Https traffic inspection HttpFox is very great tool. u'll get an add-on for firefox in the web. However it doesn't have the cool dom inspection feature of firebug.